# weblogic 10.3.5 LDAP access for a J2EE application is not working

Tags: weblogic

I am deploying a J2EE ear in weblogic 10.3.5. it uses Oracle internet directory LDAP , for authentication. after entering username and password in the login page, I was able to see the authentication Allowed in the AdminServer.logs,  but the login page is not changing.

on click of username and password I am getting the same login page again. application is not moving to other secure pages, I don't know what to do.

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the role configured in the OID LDAP server in the web.xml and weblogic.xml, after that it was started working.

at least one role of the login should be configured in web.xml and weblogic.xml, this will solve the login problem.